# Output of Powershell console is different than CSV output, but I can't understand why

Tags: powershell

I am writing a Powershell script to generate a CSV report containing Remote Desktop Services settings for a set of users in a specific Organizational Unit (OU). Although the table output showing these settings in the PowerShell console is correct, when I try to output the information to a CSV file, any fields with non-null values are replaced with "System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection" instead of the correct directory or true/false values. Can someone help me understand why the table output and the exported CSV differ and tell me what I need to change to avoid this issue? Here is the relevant code for my script:

```
$OU = "OU=Users,DC=Test,DC=Local"
$rows = @() 

$Accounts = Get-ADuser -Filter * -Searchbase $OU -Properties *
$Accounts | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_
    $UserInfo = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($user.distinguishedName)"

    # Add a new CSV row
    $rows += [PSCustomObject]@{
        User = $user.Name
        TSProfilePath = $UserInfo.TerminalServicesProfilePath
        TSHomeDir = $UserInfo.TerminalServicesHomeDirectory
        TSHomeDrive = $UserInfo.TerminalServicesHomeDrive
    }
}

$rows | Format-Table -AutoSize
$rows | Export-Csv C:\Temp\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Simply put, `your LDAP property is an object of type ```System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection```, but ```Format-Object``` and ```Export-Csv``` convert it to a string in different ways in order to output it. If you want the value to be stringified consistently you'll need to convert it to something that both cmdlets turn into the same value - something like (guessing)... ```TSProfilePath = [string] $UserInfo.TerminalServicesProfilePath[0]``` to retrieve the first (only?) value from the collection and assign it to your ```TSProfilePath``` property.